# Get _id of updated or inserted document in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

Using PyMongo, I'm calling update() to create a new document in a collection.  I'd like to use the _id of the document after it's updated or created.  How do I get the _id of the updated or newly created document?

This question is also relevant to MongoDB in general, not just PyMongo.

---

The update statement, as per request

```
db.texts.update({"title": pRef["book"], "versionTitle": text["versionTitle"], "language": text["language"]}, text, True, False)
```

Comment: Could you show how do you use `update()` to create a new document?

Comment: updated with code, above

Answer (score 0):

Instead of letting the database auto-generate the _id for your document, you could set an own _id manually. When you insert a document with an _id field already set, it will retain that value and no new one will be assigned.

You can create an ObjectId just the way the database does with [`ObjectId()`](http://api.mongodb.org/python/1.7/api/pymongo/objectid.html), but you can also assign any own value of any type to _id, as long as you can guarantee that it is unique, so when your data already has a natural key, you could consider using this as value for _id.